# WARNING: buildx: failed to read current commit information with git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree

Tags: git, docker, gradle

I am getting this warning which idk what it means but couldn't get it over my head
Here is the docker file, it is a multistage for a gradlew build

```
# Building a multistage dockerfile and that's why we use "as"
# building a code doesn't need gradle installed thaat's why jdk image is only needed

FROM openjdk:11 as base 
WORKDIR /app
#FIRST dot current directory to the other dot (work directory)
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x gradlew
RUN ./gradlew build

FROM tomcat:9
WORKDIR webapps
COPY --from=base /app/build/libs/sampleWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war .
RUN rm -rf ROOT && mv sampleWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war ROOT.war
```

doesn't seem to have to do anything with this but i am not that familiar with java app dev just general knowledge. building it on Windows and I didn't see that warning just on the Linux machine. and if it is git related i have it installed.

I didn't know where to look for, google and chatgpt was no help

Answer (score 4):

i just do:

```
git config --global --add safe.directory <your dir app>
```

and this warning desapear.

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: where does happen inside dockerfile or host

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just add the `.dockerignore` file with the following content in the same folder with the `Dockerfile`:

```
Dockerfile
.dockerignore
node_modules
npm-debug.log
dist
```

and the problem gone.

I'm using NestJS.